# NullPointerException, I cant figure out what is giving a null value

Tags: java

I'm a college student and this code is for a project in my intro to Java course.  I've worked with it over and over again, searched for answers both on stackoverflow and others websites, but I still can't figure out what the problem is. The program is meant to store Clients by prompting for a First and Last name, and a email address. The client will be given a Client ID, and they can use that to either book a storage unit, or display a booked storage unit. When I run the program I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Webstore3.WebStorage.Sub_Menu(WebStorage.java:153)
    at Webstore3.WebStorage.main(WebStorage.java:85)
```

I've seen the questions and answers on stackoverflow regarding NullPointerExceptions, and I've done test code to make sure there is something in both **input** and **customer[i].Client_ID**, but I've yet to realize what the problem is. I know that the code isn't perfect, but any and all help in getting past this first error would be greatly appreciated.

```
    package Webstore3;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.lang.StringBuilder;

    public class WebStorage
    {   
        static int c = 0;
        static int b = 0;
        static int s = 0;
        static WebStorage temp_w = new WebStorage();
        static Customer temp_c;
        static Booking temp_b;
        static Storage temp_s;
        static int i = 0;
        static int j = 0;
        static int k = 0;
        static int Confirm;
        static int Choose;
        static String input = new String("");
        static int temp = 0;
        static String temp_string = "";
        static String temp_string2 = "";
        static Random r = new Random();
        static Customer[] customer = new Customer[100];
        static Booking[] booking = new Booking[14];
        static Storage[] storage = new Storage[14];
        //static ArrayList<Customer> customer2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        //static ArrayList<Customer> booking2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        //static ArrayList<Customer> storage2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        static int w = 0;
        static int l = 0;


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            Confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to Access ~WebStorage~?");
            if(Confirm == 0)
            {
                while(temp != 3)
                {
                    temp = MainMenu();

                    if(temp == 1)
                    {
                        temp_c = new Customer();
                        temp_c.First_Name();
                        temp_c.Last_Name();
                        temp_c.Email();
                        temp_string = temp_c.Account_Created();
                        customer[c] = temp_c;

                        if(Confirm == 0 )
                        {
                            c++;
                            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to do now?" + "\n" + "\n" + "Book Unit - (1)" + "\n" + "Main Menu - (2)");
                            Choose = Integer.parseInt(input);
                            if(Choose == 1)
                            {
                                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter unit width: ");
                                w = Integer.parseInt(input);

                                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter unit length: ");
                                l = Integer.parseInt(input);

                                temp_s = new Storage();
                                temp_string2 = temp_s.Storage(w, l);
                                storage[s] = temp_s;
                                if(temp_string2 != "")
                                {
                                    temp_b = new Booking();
                                    temp_b.Storage_ID = temp_string2;
                                    temp_b.Client_ID = temp_string;
                                    booking[b] = temp_b;
                                    b++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(temp == 2)
                    {
                        Sub_Menu();
                    }
                    if(temp == 3)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

            }
            if(Confirm == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        public static int MainMenu()
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number correspoding to your desired action: " + "\n" + "\n" + "Create an Account - (1)" + "\n" + "Booking - (2)" + "\n" + "Quit Program - (3)" +"\n");
            temp = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return temp;
        }

        public static void Sub_Menu()
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number correspoding to your desired action: " + "\n" + "\n" + "Book Storage - (1)" + "\n" + "Search Booking - (2)" + "\n" + "Display all Booking - (3)" +"\n" + "Main Menu - (4)");
            Choose = Integer.parseInt(input);

            if(Choose == 1)
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Client ID: ");
                temp_string = input;

                for(i = 0; i < customer.length; i++)
                {
                    if(input == customer[i].Client_ID)
                    {
                        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter unit width: ");
                        w = Integer.parseInt(input);

                        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter unit length: ");
                        l = Integer.parseInt(input);

                        temp_s = new Storage();
                        temp_string2 = temp_s.Storage(w, l);
                        storage[s] = temp_s;
                        if(temp_string2 != "")
                        {
                            temp_b = new Booking();
                            temp_b.Storage_ID = temp_string2;
                            temp_b.Client_ID = temp_string;
                            booking[b] = temp_b;
                            b++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client ID not found!" + "\n" + "\n" + "Press ok, to return to the main menu and create an account");
            }
            if(Choose == 2)
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Client ID: ");


                for(i = 0; i < customer.length; i++)
                {
                    if(input == customer[i].Client_ID)
                    {
                        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Storage ID: ");

                        for(i = 0; i < storage.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(input == storage[i].Storage_ID)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "size: " + storage[i].sb2 + "\n" + "Rental: " + storage[i].price_h + "\n" + "Storage ID: " + storage[i].sb + "\n" + "\n" + "Press ok, to return to the Main menu");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(Choose == 3)
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter you Client ID: ");

                for(i = 0; i < customer.length; i++)
                {
                    if(input == customer[i].Client_ID)
                    {
                        for(j = 0; j < booking.length; j++)
                        {
                            if(input == booking[j].Client_ID)
                            {
                                for(k = 0; k < storage.length; k++)
                                {
                                    if(booking[j].Storage_ID == storage[k].Storage_ID)
                                    {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First Name: " + customer[i].Client_FirstName + "\n" + "Last Name: " + customer[i].Client_LastName + "\n"+ "Email: " + customer[i].Client_Email + "\n" + "size: " + storage[k].sb2 + "\n" + "Rental: " + storage[k].price_h + "\n" + "Storage ID: " + storage[k].sb + "\n" + "\n");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(Choose == 4)
            {

            }


        }

    }

    class Customer extends WebStorage
    {
        static String input = new String("");
        static boolean error;
        static int Confirm = 0;
        static int Valid_Email = 0;
        static int Valid_ID = 0;
         String Client_FirstName = "";
         String Client_LastName = "";
         String Client_Number = "";
         String Client_Email = "";
        static int[] temp_array = new int[9];
        static int[] Client_ID_Array = new int[9];
         String Client_ID = ""; 
         StringBuilder sb;

         Customer()
            {
                Client_FirstName = new String("");
                Client_LastName = new String("");
                Client_Number = new String("");
                Client_Email = new String("");
                Client_ID = new String("");
                sb = new StringBuilder("");
            }

            Customer(String Client_FirstName, String Client_LastName, String Client_Number, String Client_Email, String Client_ID, StringBuilder sb)
            {
                this.Client_FirstName = Client_FirstName;
                this.Client_LastName = Client_LastName;
                this.Client_Number = Client_Number;
                this.Client_Email = Client_Email;
                this.Client_ID = Client_ID;
                this.sb = sb;


            }

        public void First_Name()
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Information to create an account: " + "\n" + "\n" + "First Name: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {
                error = Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i));
                if(error == false)
                {
                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your name may only contain letters" + "\n" + "\n" + "First Name: ");
                    error = Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i));
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
            Client_FirstName = input;
        }

        public void Last_Name ()
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Information to create an account: " + "\n" + "\n" + "Last Name: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {
                error = Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i));
                if(error == false)
                {
                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your name may only contain letters" + "\n" + "\n" + "Last Name: ");
                    error = Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i));
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
            Client_LastName = input;
        }

        public void Email ()
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Information to create an account: " + "\n" + "\n" + "Email: (Must contain a @, and end with .com, .net, .org, or .edu) ");
            while(Valid_Email < 2)
            {
                Valid_Email = 0;

                error = input.contains("@");
                if(error == true)
                {
                    Valid_Email++;
                }
                error = input.contains(".com");
                if(error == true)
                {
                    Valid_Email++;
                }
                error = input.contains(".net");
                if(error == true)
                {
                    Valid_Email++;
                }
                error = input.contains(".org");
                if(error == true)
                {
                    Valid_Email++;
                }
                error = input.contains(".edu");
                if(error == true)
                {
                    Valid_Email++;
                }

                if(Valid_Email < 2)
                {
                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid email entered! " + "\n" + "\n" + "Email: (Must contain a @, and end with .com, .net, .org, or .edu)  ");
                }
            }

            Client_Email = input;

        }

        public String Account_Created()
        {
            Confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Account Created!" + "\n" + "Is everything correct?" + "\n" + "First Name: " + Client_FirstName + "\n" + "Last Name: " + Client_LastName + "\n"+ "Email: " + Client_Email);
            if(Confirm == 0)
            {
                do{
                    for(i = 0; i < temp_array.length; i++)
                    {
                        temp_array[i] = r.nextInt(9);
                    }
                    for(i = 0; i < customer.length; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j < Client_ID_Array.length; j++)
                        {
                            if(temp_array[j] == customer[i].Client_ID_Array[j])
                            {
                                Valid_ID++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }while(Valid_ID == 9);
                Client_ID_Array = temp_array;
                for(i = 0; i < Client_ID_Array.length; i++)
                {
                    sb.append(Client_ID_Array[i]);
                }
                Client_ID = sb.toString();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Client ID#: " + Client_ID );
            }

            return Client_ID;
        }


    }

    class Booking extends WebStorage
    {
         String Client_ID;
         String Storage_ID;
        static int i = 0;
         String temp_string = "";
         String input = "";
        static int Choose = 0;
        static int Choose2 = 0;
        static int w = 0;
        static int l = 0;


        Booking()
        {
            Client_ID = "";
            Storage_ID = "";
            temp_string = "";
            input = "";
        }

        Booking(String Client_ID, String Storage_ID, String temp_string, String input)
        {
            this.Client_ID = Client_ID;
            this.Storage_ID = Storage_ID;
            this.temp_string = temp_string;
            this.input = input;
        }


    }

    class Storage extends WebStorage
    {
        static int Confirm = 0;
        static int[] width  = { 5,  5, 10, 10,  10,  10,  10};
        static int[] length = { 5, 10, 10, 15,  20,  25,  30};
        static int[] unit   = { 3,  3,  2,  2,   2,   1,   1};
        static int[] price  = {16, 33, 41, 73, 163, 245, 277};
        static int price_h = 0;
        static int total_units = 1;
         String Storage_ID = "";
         StringBuilder sb;
         StringBuilder sb2;
        static char by = 'x';

        Storage()
        {
            Storage_ID = "";
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        }

        Storage(String Storage_ID, StringBuilder sb, StringBuilder sb2)
        {
            this.Storage_ID = Storage_ID;
            this.sb = sb;
            this.sb2 = sb2;
        }


        public String Storage(int w, int l)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < width.length; i++)
            {
                if(w == width[i] && l == length[i] && unit[i] > 0)
                {
                        if(total_units < 10)
                        {
                            sb.append(0);
                            sb.append(total_units);
                        }
                        if(total_units > 9)
                        {
                            sb.append(total_units);
                        }
                        if(width[i] < 10)
                        {
                            sb.append(0);
                            sb.append(w);
                            if(length[i] < 10)
                            {
                                sb.append(0);
                                sb.append(l);
                            }
                            if(length[i] > 9)
                            {
                                sb.append(l);
                            }
                        }
                        if(width[i] > 9)
                        {
                            sb.append(w);
                            if(length[i] < 10)
                            {
                                sb.append(0);
                                sb.append(l);
                            }
                            if(length[i] > 9)
                            {
                                sb.append(l);
                            }
                        }
                    unit[i] = unit[i] - 1;
                    total_units = total_units + 1;

                    sb2.append(w);
                    sb2.append(by);
                    sb2.append(l);

                    price_h = price[i];

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Storage Booked!" + "\n" + "\n" + "size: " + sb2 + "\n" + "Rental: " + price_h + "\n" + "Storage ID: " + sb );

                    Storage_ID = sb.toString();

                    WebStorage.s++;

                }
                if((w != width[i] && l !=length[i]) && unit[i] <= 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No storage units of that size are available");
                }
                if(total_units == 14)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All storage units are occupied!");
                }
            }

            return Storage_ID;
        }
```

Comment: Here is a one-word answer: _debugger_

Comment: As the Exception tells you, you are probably trying to acces a method or an attribute of a null Object, at line 153 of WebStorage.java.

Comment: small recommendation: adopt good naming conventions, it 'll make your code easier to read for those trying to help you. static int Confirm;
        static int Choose;, for instance, should be confirm and choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at those points.

You declare an array of `Customer` with a size of 100.

```
static Customer[] customer = new Customer[100];
```

later in the code you loop over all array entries

```
for(i = 0; i < customer.length; i++)
```

But you do not check if at index `i` is already a reference to a `Customer` is stored. If not you get a `NUllPointerException`.

```
if(input == customer[i].Client_ID)
```